# Calling a void function (in win32) from C# with parameters

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, dll, dllimport

I have the following code in win32, which sets a hook in a target application.

```
void InstallHook(DWORD ThreadId)
{
    g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, CallWndProc, g_hInstDll, ThreadId); 
}
```

**I wish to call this function from C# (.net).**

I have this so far:

```
[DllImport("TheHookDll.dll")]
public extern static void InstallHook(UInt32 ThreadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

and I call it like this:

```
IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "MyTargetAppWindowTitle");

UInt32 threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero);

InstallHook(threadID);
```

This gives me the handle(hWnd) for the target, and the threadID which is used in the InstallHook function in win32. (It’s just decimals instead of hex)

But I get this error messages:

> PInvokeStackImbalance was detected Message: A call to PInvoke function
>   'TheOperator!TheOperator.Form1::InstallHook' has unbalanced the stack.
>   This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match
>   the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and
>   parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged
>   signature.

I have tried to change the Calling Convention in my dll file (configuration properties -> C/C++ -> All Options -> Calling Convention) from __cdel to __stdcall, but without any luck. (same error)

What am I doing wrong?

I have changed the DWORD to UInt32, because c# do not support DWORD etc. But is that the right way to do it?

Any hints?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx): "DWORD - A 32-bit unsigned integer. The range is 0 through 4294967295 decimal." So the matching C# type is indeed `UInt32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your PInvoke like this:

```
    [DllImport("TheHookDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static void InstallHook(UInt32 ThreadId);
```

Reason being that when you call this specific function, the caller needs to clean the stack. Without explicitly specifying this in your PInvoke signature, the runtime won't clean the stack and therefore it'll mess the stack up resulting in the error message you've been seeing.

If you don't specify a `CallingConvention` explicitly, the runtime assumes the function you are trying to call is an `StdCall`, in which the callee cleans the stack. That's not the case, and the stack will be left all messed up and dirty.

Other than that your signature looks correct; a `DWORD` is indeed a `uint` or `UInt32` in C#. If that one gets you into trouble, you could try decorating it with the `MarshalAs` attribute and have the Marshal return it as unmanaged type `U8`.